# How to extract unique values from one column based on criteria from two other columns, with or statement?

Tags: excel, list, indexing, excel-formula, unique

My data set looks something like this:

```
ID  Name1   Name2
1   Jack    Tom
1   Tom     Tom
1   Lisa    Tom
2   Tom 
2   Tom 
3   Frank   Frank
3   John    Frank
3   Frank   Frank
3   John    Frank
4           Tom
4           Tom
5   Lisa    
5   Jack
```

and I want the following output:

```
Result
1
2
4
```

Note: I want the unique IDs for Tom if "Tom" shows in one of the two name columns.

I tried to use the following formula:

```
IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($B$14); MATCH(0; IF($B$10=INDIRECT($B$16); IF($B$10=INDIRECT($B$15); COUNTIF($E$27:E27; INDIRECT($B$14)); "")); 0));"")
```

The problem is that this only gives me ID nr 1 as output since Tom shows up in both columns in this case. I think I need to implement an OR-statement to the formula.

Explanation of my formula:

- Indirect(B14): array for the call IDs. B14 contains a name of this array.
- B10: Contains the name I want to match (i.e. "Tom")
- Indirect(B16): column Name1
- Indirect(B15): column Name2

Good answers will be rewarded:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your formula (without INDIRECT statements) and added ISNUMBER & FIND in order to find "Tom" in a combination of columns B and C:

This is an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$14,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Tom",$B$1:$B$14&$C$1:$C$14)),$A$1:$A$14,"")),0)),"")
```

Result:

[image]

I couldn't use INDIRECT references as I'm not sure what exactly they point to (i.e. what are the ranges  & column names). I hope it won't be too difficult for you to modify my formula in order to match your references.

Hope it helps! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, even with my indirect function:) I use indirect since I have a dynamic name of the range in one specific cell in a Dashboard sheet.I.e I have named different arrays in another sheet manually.